# Best practices to share users between tenants in a multi-tenancy environment

Tags: database-design, architecture, multi-tenant

I am currently considering to create a web application that enables teachers to create a class and add pupils to their class. Now the pupils should be created by the teacher (including all contact data like phone number etc.). Each teacher should be considered an independent tenant.

Now at some point in the platform a pupil will have to end up in two different classes by two different teachers. However I want said pupil to have to consent to their data being stored and not automatically share personal info across tenants. At some point in the future they should also be able to log in themselves and adjust what data they allow which teacher to access.

A use case would be that a pupil attends a french and a math class. They want the french teacher to have the cell phone number to be able to give them a call in case class gets cancelled, but not the math teacher.

So all in all the app should be multi-tenancy aware but at the same time allow for some flexibility for the users.

Any suggestions on reading on best practices and such an unorthodox multi-tenancy concept?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a multi tenant problem, it is more a rights problem within a single web application.

This is actually built in functionality in the free version of SharePoint.  To do this in SharePoint you would:

- Create a site template for a student
- The teacher would create a site for each student based on the template
- The teacher would give the student admin rights on his/her site
- The student could then give anyone they wanted read rights.